# neo4j syntax error when using WHERE NOT IN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out all the cities that don't have a direct flight to BOM. My query looks like this so far, but it says I have a syntax error with mismatched input "." on the first line. How do I subtract all the cities that do have the direct flight to BOM from all the departure cities for all flights? Newcomer to neo4j.

```
MATCH(n.source_airport_code) WHERE NOT IN ( MATCH (n:Flight)
WHERE n.destination_airport_code = "BOM"
RETURN DISTINCT n.source_airport_code)
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in this query: 1. `MATCH` can only target nodes and relationships, not properties. 2. Cypher does not (yet) support subqueries

Comment: I saw that WHERE NOT IN was an option, or that maybe collect() could work. How would I go about this if subqueries weren't supported yet though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by Gabor's comment, Cypher does not support subqueries. If I understood completely your requirement, you can achieve your goal doing two different `MATCH`s in conjunction with [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function and [DISTINCT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#syntax-using-the-distinct-operator) operator. Try:

```
MATCH (n:Flight)
WHERE n.destination_airport_code = "BOM"
WITH collect(DISTINCT n.source_airport_code) as codes
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT n.source_airport_code IN codes
RETURN n
```